# Meteor method is triggering HTTP call when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor method for adding an email address to a collection and then submitting it to sendgrid.

```
export const insertEmail = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'emails.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    email: { type: String }
  }).validator(),
  run(email) {
    let isPresent = Emails.find({email: email.email}).count();

    var isEmailValid = function(address) {
      return /^[A-Z0-9'.1234z_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(address);
    };

    if( isPresent < 1 && isEmailValid(email.email) ) {
      Emails.insert({email: email.email, ip: '1'});

      try {
        HTTP.call('POST',
          'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients', {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + Meteor.settings.sendGridMarketingKey,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            content: '[{\"email\": \"' + email.email + '\"}]'
          }, function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
              // throw new Meteor.Error(500, error);
            } else {
              return success
            }
          });
      } catch(error) {
        // throw new Meteor.Error(500, error);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'This Email is Already Added!')
    }
  },
});
```

The submission and addition to the Emails collection works great but I have 2 issues:

1) Even though it works, I get a POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients 403 (FORBIDDEN) This happens even when I type an email that has already been added and the 'This email is already added' error gets triggered. Does anyone know why I am getting a POST error when I don't see a corresponding duplicate addition of an email to my collection? I'd naively think that if I screwed up the logic and I am calling the HTTP method when I shouldn't, I would also be triggering the Email.insert method at the same time, but the HTTP method seems to trigger on its own even when there isn't an email.email present which then gives that forbidden error.

2) I can't figure out how to properly add someone's IP address to the collection. I previously used this command and it worked, but it doesn't seem to work here because it is in a ValidateMethod:

```
var ipAddress = this.connection.clientAddress;
check(ipAddress, String);
```

Comment: You can try to extract the option argument and log it. I think the issue comes from the content, maybe you should try to create a real object in js and just `JSON.stringify` it instead of concatenating strings together.

Comment: Thanks! I used `let emailAddress = JSON.stringify(email.email);` and then used `emailAddress` to refer to that value for the rest of the post and that worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
content: '[{\"email\": \"' + email.email + '\"}]'
```

into

```
const content = JSON.stringify([{email: email.email}])
const options = {
     headers: {...},
     content: content
}
[...]
HTTP.call(type, url, options, function (err, data) {});
```

to ensure that your post data will be correctly sent.